# Scaling HTML5 webpage based on the window's size

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm attempting to take an HTML5 webpage with two canvas elements on it and scale everything down and up as the window for the webpage does. Here's my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <div id="treeArea"class="container" style="width:100%">
        <canvas id="canvas" class="canvas" width="3920" height="2080" style="z-  index:1;"></canvas>
        <canvas id="animCanvas" class="canvas" width="3920" height="2080" style="z-index:2;"></canvas>
    </div>
    <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
    <output id="list"></output>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="leafNodes.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload=initialise()>
</body>
</html>
```

The part that works correctly is

```
<div id="treeArea"class="container" style="width:100%">
```

However, I can't figure out how to scale the height in the same manner. I've tried the obvious by just placing height:100% in, but that doesn't work.

**Also I'm new to HTML5 and CSS so be generous with the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got your DOM elements inside of the `head` tag instead of `body` tag. After fixing that setting `height: 100%` should work.